# Overheating Toshiba Satellite L300

Tags: laptop

A coleague of mine's having trouble with his new *Toshiba Satellite L300* ... I tool a kook at it, and indeed it's hot as hell. I couldn't hold my hand on it for too long. He says it also has a tendency to turn itself off (WinXP 32bit running) with no forewarning. Hasn't happened to me while I was using it, but that wasn't long anyways.

The first guess was it was too dirty ... problem is it's new, came out of a package a quarter of a year ago. Kept in a clean environment (office). Looks clean. No dust in sight.
Second guess is that the fan wasn't working properly, cause indeed it has intervals of working, and non working. But when I listen to it, it sounds like normal usage.

I took a SpeedFan measurement, and it reports temp. up to 85 Celsius ... which is definitely too high.

Anyone knows what else I could do to it ?

*It is under warranty and it will go to the service, but I thought if there is something we can do, as to avoid carrying it there / be without it for a week ...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing thermal paste fits the symptoms, but seeing as it's a laptop I would get it fixed under warranty.

Comment: that will most probably be the solution. but since we can't get it there before the end of the week, and it always takes them some time, i just thought i'd try fishing for a few novel ideas first :-)

Comment: i wouldn't think thermal paste would be in that bad shape on a new laptop. or is it something that happens regularly ?

Comment: @Idigas I'm not sure - my guess is that the thermal paste was forgotten about entirely. And a little dust build-up after a few months of use probably pushed it over the edge.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take it to be serviced as you really don't want to mess around with something like that.  Other than checking the BIOS and getting a Chillmat it sounds like you have been fairly diligent in researching the problem.